# When open dialog System.AccessViolationException:Attempted to read or write protected memory.This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, runtime-error

I have made a C# project. Every thing is working fine when i run project through Visual Studio 2010. After that i have created setup for this solution and when i tried to open the dialog box then it showed the above error. After running project from setup file it also making trouble to write into database.
Here is the complete stack of exception that came on access of dialog.

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ******* *Exception Text* ********* System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>   at System.Windows.Forms.FileDialogNative.IFileDialog.Show(IntPtr
>   parent)    at System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialogVista(IntPtr
>   hWndOwner)    at System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialog(IntPtr
>   hWndOwner)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog()    at
>   Email_Client.ImportContacts.btnBrowse_Click(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in E:\Development.net Projects\Email Client\Email
>   Client\ImportContacts.cs:line 35    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Please help.

Comment: What use is a stack trace w/o the code that generates it?

Comment: Yep. You have a bug. probably in ImportContacts.cs at line 35. What, you want more info? Same here...

Answer (score 0):

I was the same problem and i solved it by install Hotfix 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=2516475&kbln=en-US
in my case the problem occured because i use accdb instead of mdb 
vb.net or c#